# Getting issue java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418) for Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I had checked many things related to this nothing worked for me.

```
SqlRowSet userTypesqlRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(USER_TYPE_QUERY, parameters);
```

For this line, I am getting the error.

All the thing working on another system.

I have checked all the libraries.

I verified all the properties.

Find below error log for issue.

```
17:57:33,070 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1) java.lang.NullPointerException
17:57:33,070 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
17:57:33,070 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
17:57:33,086 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
17:57:33,086 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.<init>(PropertyResourceBundle.java:111)
17:57:33,086 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.<init>(Unknown Source)
17:57:33,086 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.getJdbcRowSetResourceBundle(Unknown Source)
17:57:33,102 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
17:57:33,102 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.newCachedRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:78)
17:57:33,102 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.createSqlRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:62)
17:57:33,117 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:46)
...

17:57:33,336 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
17:57:33,351 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
17:57:33,351 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1) org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error in loading user ,Please contact system Admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the com.sun.rowset.jar file in my project.

This jar default work for the US-English location and language.

So I Updated above thing for my system.

Now it's working as expected.